# Search for a url in a string and remove enclosing tag

Tags: c#

I have a string in which I need to search for a url and get its immediate enclosing script tag and remove it.

example

```
string test="<script>test</script><script 
src="https://cdn.getsmartcontent.com/xxxxx.js"></script><script></script>"
```

should give

```
string test="<script>test</script><script></script>"
```

The xxxxx.js can be any alphanumeric name

Comment: Your example code doesn't compile.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Why do you need to do this? What is the _underlying_ problem?

Comment: What have you done so far ? Url contains http, did you try to find it and substring etc?

Comment: @mjwills that comment made my day

Comment: Jade lets read between the lines here, Do want to scrape a web page for the scripts?

Comment: I have 13000 sharepoint sites and for each site I have to parse the master page and remove the above specific script tag

Comment: So search for "<script 
src="https://cdn.getsmartcontent.com/xxxxx.js"></script>" and replace it with nothing

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Show your code you have tried to do that with, and what failed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The correct answer is use the *HTML Agility Pack* and parse the html properly**

However, in regards to you comment

> I have 13000 sharepoint sites and for each site I have to parse the
>   master page and remove the above specific script tag

You can use something nasty like this i guess :/

```
Regex.Replace(yourPage, @"<script src=""https://cdn.getsmartcontent.com/.+?\/script>", String.Empty);
```

You could use the multiline option i guess, but this is still a bad idea

***Note/Disclaimer/Warning*** : See bold comment

Comment: wouldn't this replace all the script tags in master page?

Comment: Isnt that want you what ?

Comment: @JadeRoone if not please explain

Comment: just want to replace the tag containing the url https://cdn.getsmartcontent.com/xxxxx.js

Comment: @JadeRoone something like that. but i really do advise not to use regex, spaces and new lines between script and source will break it